# Running deep-daze on nvidia jetson - "Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement torchvision>=0.8.2"

Tags: python, pytorch, torchvision, nvidia-jetson, nvidia-jetson-nano

I have an nvidia Jetson Nano (the 4gb version).  I am attempting to run this project on it: https://github.com/lucidrains/deep-daze

I am attempting to run the command `pip install deep-daze`.  However, I do not have pip so I am running `pip3 install deep-daze`.  When I run that I get

```
chris@chris-desktop:~$ pip3 install deep-daze
Collecting deep-daze
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/f1/ed/b3f3d9d92f5a48932b3807f683642b28da75722ae93da2f9bdc6af5f1768/deep_daze-0.7.2-py3-none-any.whl
Collecting tqdm (from deep-daze)
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/f8/3e/2730d0effc282960dbff3cf91599ad0d8f3faedc8e75720fdf224b31ab24/tqdm-4.59.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (74kB)
    100% |████████████████████████████████| 81kB 2.4MB/s 
Collecting torchvision>=0.8.2 (from deep-daze)
  Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement torchvision>=0.8.2 (from deep-daze) (from versions: 0.1.6, 0.1.7, 0.1.8, 0.1.9, 0.2.0, 0.2.1, 0.2.2, 0.2.2.post2, 0.2.2.post3)
No matching distribution found for torchvision>=0.8.2 (from deep-daze)
```

I am pretty unfamiliar with several of the moving parts here and not sure how to fix this.  I thought these version numbers may be useful in answering this question:

```
chris@chris-desktop:~$ python3 --version
Python 3.6.9
chris@chris-desktop:~$ pip3 --version
pip 9.0.1 from /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages (python 3.6)
chris@chris-desktop:~$ python2 --version
Python 2.7.17
chris@chris-desktop:~$ pip2 --version
bash: pip2: command not found
chris@chris-desktop:~$ pip --version
bash: pip: command not found
chris@chris-desktop:~$ cat /etc/os-release
NAME="Ubuntu"
VERSION="18.04.5 LTS (Bionic Beaver)"
ID=ubuntu
ID_LIKE=debian
PRETTY_NAME="Ubuntu 18.04.5 LTS"
VERSION_ID="18.04"
HOME_URL="https://www.ubuntu.com/"
SUPPORT_URL="https://help.ubuntu.com/"
BUG_REPORT_URL="https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/"
PRIVACY_POLICY_URL="https://www.ubuntu.com/legal/terms-and-policies/privacy-policy"
VERSION_CODENAME=bionic
UBUNTU_CODENAME=bionic
```

Comment: I think nvidia provides wheels for pytorch and may be torchvision, https://forums.developer.nvidia.com/t/pytorch-for-jetson-version-1-8-0-now-available/72048 and also you have to install JetPack too

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to the comment from Elbek I got this working!  I was able to follow the guide here: https://forums.developer.nvidia.com/t/pytorch-for-jetson-version-1-8-0-now-available/72048

Unfortunately after I got everything installed I ran into an issue with not having enough memory, but, it all got installed.